# How does importing work in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

If you have a module, E.G: `some_module.py`, which contains variables and functions, E.G:

```
SOME_LIST = ["list items"]     #Doesn't really matter

def some_function():
    do_something

def some_other_function():
    do something using SOME_LIST & some_function()
```

This would then be imported from another file.

When importing, does Python run the entire script or just the part needed?

Comment: All statements in the file are executed...

Comment: @AChampion Can I have a reference for this?

Comment: before claiming it may be a duplicate, you should run a search to see if you can find such a duplicate and if it answers your question (◔_◔)

Comment: Agreed. I didn't find anything.

Comment: Python runs all code that is not in a function at import time and the code inside the function when you call it.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) "6.1. More on Modules
A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the first time the module name is encountered in an import statement."

Comment: Post it as an answer.